# How to set libraries for linker in cmake?

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

I've downloaded SDL library and was able to set the include path without any troubles but setting up the linker is a complete nightmare... How am I suppose to point cmake to correct files?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(simple_timeline_recorder)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/")

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/SDL/include")
target_link_libraries(simple_timeline_recorder)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(simple_timeline_recorder ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

~Thanks for help

edit (vsoftco)>

Unfortunately it does not work for some reason. I'm using CLion from jetbrains with mingw. I've tried with extension and without and I've also tried giving absolute path. No use. The error / exception is the same.

```
...

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/SDL/include")

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -LDependencies/SDL/lib/win32/SDL2")

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(simple_timeline_recorder ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(simple_timeline_recorder SDL2)
```

Error message:

```
Linking CXX executable simple_timeline_recorder.exe
d:/apps/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\simple_timeline_recorder.dir\build.make:87: recipe for target 'simple_timeline_recorder.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:59: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/simple_timeline_recorder.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [simple_timeline_recorder.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/simple_timeline_recorder.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:74: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't seem to have specified the path to the library you want to link against.
Let's say you want to include `mylib.so` from `/path/to/mylib`. What you can do is adding to your `CMakeLists.txt` the line

```
SET (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L/path/to/mylib")
```

then in the last line of the `CMakeLists.txt` (after the `ADD_EXECUTABLE` clause) use

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(simple_timeline_recorder mylib)
```

**UPDATED EDIT**

Try

```
SET (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/SDL/lib/win32/SDL2")
```

so you can be sure you get the right path.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not worked for me. I've provided details in my first post. I'm probably doing something wrong. :/

Comment: @starach See updated edit. It should work, if not it is indeed very strange.

Comment: Looks to me I've been doing many things wrong. Check out my own response for that issue. But still thanks. You have put me on a right track. :)

Comment: I give up it "was working" and now another error about missing library pops up... back to visual studio I guess...

Comment: @starach try building it small, step by step (first an example without the lib, then with it) until you figure out what's going on. In principle, it should work. You can also check the generated Makefiles and see what's missing there.